# How do I do this with Chinese text?

Tags: python, pyautogui, cjk

The below works well for English, but not Chinese lyrics.

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
f = open('/Users/a27/爱.txt', 'r','UTF-8')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

It says `str object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. How can I process Chinese strings?

Comment: You do _what_ exactly?

Comment: Messing with my friend with spams :D

Comment: Than all of SO questions are "_processing information_" - learn to describe what you want to achieve technically and what is wrong. Right now I can suggest you to change your friend and see if that solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you are opening the file. Try to use the following syntax:
`with open('/Users/a27/爱.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Edited code:

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
with open('/Users/a27/爱.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for word in f:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
```